# Setting PK is clustered using EF6 fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

It's been bugging me that I have to use migration to set a primary key to not clustered but I'm not able to use fluent API to set it.

Is there any way/hack to extend fluent API to support setting primary key IsClustered property in a way that when we add a migration the generated C# code shows a correct implementation too?

Answer (score 1):

The fluent API is mainly targeted at *mapping*, not database design. I think it should stay that way. API's shouldn't mix concerns. Rules concerning clustered indexes don't belong in a mapping API. It has no bearing on a *mapping* whether an index is clustered or not. Moreover the rules on clustered indexes are database-specific, so they can be only be implemented in a [Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.iqueryable.provider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). But the mapping API has no knowledge of any provider.

In my personal opinion, even the `IndexAttribute` (introduced in EF 6.1) was an insensible compromise. (Although apparently it preluded on mapping foreign key associations to unique indexes, which [will be supported in EF7](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support)).

Conversely, the `HasKey` method, although deeply involved in database design rules too, does make sense, because EF needs to know an entity's primary key. It's pivotal in all CRUD actions. And 'primary key' is a concept that all RDBMS vendors share.

Answer (score 1):

For EF 7 it has been made easy. You can use the following option with the haskey option.

```
ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```

we can use it like

```
supplierItemEntity.HasKey(supplierItem => supplierItem.SupplierItemId).ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);

 supplierItemEntity.HasIndex(s => new { s.ItemId }).ForSqlServerIsClustered(true).HasName("IX_SupplierItem_ItemId");
```

[image]